# React Events behavior

Tags: javascript, events, dom, reactjs

I'm trying use `React events` to access a custom 'value' assigned to a button, but I get different results depending on where I click on the button. I can probably use `getDOMNode()` or `this.state` to get the desired result but I'm little confused on how to use 'React Events' and it's behavior.

Is it best to use synthetic events on a single element like `<input>`? Is there a way to get the value of a button using react events?

Note: I'm using bootstrap glyphicon inside the `<button>` element.

```
var Content = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function(e) {
        console.log( e.target );
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button type="button" value="button1" className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.handleClick}><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Submit</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdshrestha/v27bqL5y/)

console.log( e.target ) results:

1. Move the mouse over the glyphicon 'check mark', and click.

   ```
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" data-reactid=".0.0.0"></span>
   ```
2. Move the mouse over the word 'Submit' and click

   ```
   <span data-reactid=".0.0.1"> Submit</span>
   ```
3. Move the mouse anywhere else inside the button, and click

   ```
   <button type="button" value="button1" class="btn btn-default" data-reactid=".0.0"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" data-reactid=".0.0.0"></span><span data-reactid=".0.0.1"> Submit</span></button>
   ```

I'm new to synthetic events and DOM behaviors as you guys can tell. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want `e.currentTarget.getAttribute('value')`

Using `currentTarget` will get the button since the event will bubble up to the button. You are getting the span element since you're likely clicking the span. That's what the value of `target` is.

Also here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v27bqL5y/1/

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use [refs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html). If you want to stay away from using stuff like `e.currentTarget`, this can be a simpler way to go.

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v27bqL5y/2/